# Find out the common parts of all the strings

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, search, match

I have a large array have almost 10000 strings, I want to find all the common part (which is longer than 3 chars)in these strings and get the occurrence of these parts.

I implement with my simple method with javascript, but it really cost a lot of time, even I did some optimization on that, for a short array of 1000 strings, it cost about 8s for Firefox and 12s for Chrome.

So I wonder if there are any related technology or algorithm, as I think it is really a common  problem which could be raised in many application.

Comment: Getting all common occurrences of all sequences 3 letters or greater is a common problem? Maybe you need to describe what you want to do with this data. I have a feeling you may have decided on the wrong approach to a problem.

Comment: you might study how packer works, it's pretty quick, but it also relies on word boundries, not just any 3 chars...

Comment: Do you mean a common *prefix*, a common *substring*, or possibly several substrings?

Comment: Hi, @cookiemonster these strings mostly are not the short one(more that 15 or even 30 chars), by finding them out, then I can replace them, highlight them ect.

Comment: Is caching an option?

Comment: @dandavis does packer means compress application like RAR 7Z or ZIP?

Comment: @Haven: yes and no. rar/zip (which you can also do in js) are binary, packer's output is still plain text, with substitution characters. the packer output has both the redacted template and and array of the most common replacements.

Comment: @Haven: Is it meant to be in response to the user typing into an input field? If so, usually that can just be done on the fly without performance issues, even with 10,000 strings.

Comment: @Iserni, but not suffix, or prefix, a method could find out a common part occures in arbitrary position :)

Comment: @ankr this time is these 10000 strings, next time maybe those 10000 strings, they may result different result of different common parts. so I don't think cache is possible

Comment: @dandavis thanks, do you have any reference or links?

Comment: Perhaps you can post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or the markup for the 'simple method' you have already tried? It might help us better understand what we're dealing with.

Comment: You can build the generalized [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of your strings (the SA of the concatenation "a$b$c$..." where $ is the negative infinity character and a, b, c, ... are your strings). This is possible in linear time. With LCP information and a set data structure you can then find the longest common substring in linear time. The algorithm is described [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree) in terms of suffix trees, but suffix arrays are simpler, faster and do the job just as well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array of all possible substrings, sort them and then look for blocks of consecutive equal strings.

The implementation below looks for suffixes of a certain length and imposes a minimal number of matches. It is not clear what you want exactly, but you need some constraints. It is easy to look for the longest common suffixes, but if you just want common suffixes, what does that mean? Are 20 occurences of a 4-character string better than 10 occurrences of a 5-character string?

Also, note that the code below does not check for overlapping strings. If you look for matches of length 4 and have 30 words with `"green"` in it, the result will contain both `"gree"` and `"reen"`.

It might not be what you want, but it should be easy to adapt. And it's reasonably fast. On 10,000 randomly generated strings with about 30 chars each, it takes less than a second to find common substrings of length 10 and maybe 4 seconds for 1000,000 strings.

Anyway, here goes:

```
/*
 *      Return an array of all substrings of the given length
 *      that occur at least mincount times in all the strings in
 *      the input array strings.
 */
function substrings(strings, length, mincount) {
    var suffix = [];
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        var s = strings[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < s.length - length + 1; j++) {
            suffix.push(s.substr(j, length));
        }
    }

    suffix.sort();
    suffix.push("");

    var last = "";
    var count = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < suffix.length; i++) {
        var s = suffix[i];

        if (s == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count >= mincount) res.push(last);
            count = 1;
        }
        last = s;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I adapt this method to all the substring (not only suffix, with minLength is 4, and the min occurrence is 5), which is faster for dealing with 10,000 strings(4s totally), I think the speed is `O(n∑k +n)`,where n denote to the number of strings, k denote to the length of each string.

Comment: @Haven can you please share your version. Thanks

Comment: @Noitidart Hey, it's already a old question, I have solved this question now, check it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/common-substrings)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Haven its just that I needed to do the same thing so was hoping to see the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Crossfilter http://square.github.io/crossfilter/  It will do whatever kind of map-reduce you want. Javascript can be very slow for searching through big messes, though. Depending on your constraints, and how that 10,000 strings will grow over time, you might think of an RDMS, like MySQL, since they are designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue where I needed to find the common prefixes across each word not just common substrings which could be in the middle or end of the word.  This function will return the common prefixes across a set of words.

```
        function findCommonPrefixes (words, min) {
            const result = new Set();
            for (const word of words) {
                let partial = word.toLowerCase();
                do {
                    const otherWords = words.filter(w => w !== word).map(w => w.toLowerCase());
                    for (const word of otherWords) {
                        if (word.includes(partial)) {
                            result.add(partial);
                            partial = '';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (partial) {
                        partial = partial.slice(0, (partial.length - 1))
                    }
                } while (partial.length && partial.length >= min)
            }
            return Array.from(result);
        }
```